# How can I search a JSON file with given argument with Python?

Tags: python, json, python-3.x, discord.py, lookup

I'm currently making an "info [argument]" command for discord.py bot that will search and return a value

So the user would say: "!Info bookshelf"
the bot would look up "bookshelf" in the JSON file and find `bookshelf = Shelf full of books` and pull the value describing the bookshelf and send it in chat.

I'm new to coding so this would help so much! Thank you in advance <3

working on Python 3.9

Comment: What have you tried already? Do you have any code samples?

Comment: What format is your json file in? That will influence how you reference the file. Which part in particular are you having trouble with?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quite a simple solution: You would just take the arguments from the command (in this case "bookcase"), then parse it in to a search.

```py
def lookup(args):
    look = data[args]
    return look
```